# Error happened when using vim to do the git commit action: Error detected while processing function PyKiteEvent

Tags: python, zsh

I have run into a problem when I want to do the `git commit`, but the error poped out and as shown below:

```
"~/xxx/xxx/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 10L, 411C
Error detected while processing function PyKiteEvent:
line  143:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 5, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/V
ersions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so, 2): no suitable image
 found.  Did find:
^I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/py
thon2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so: code signature in (/usr/local/opt/pytho
n/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_s
truct.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped
 file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-ho
c signed.
```

How can I solve this problem? 
I am using zsh and my MacOS is Majove version. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't look like an error message related to git. Afaik git is written in `C` and a few pieces of `bash` and this is definitely a `python` error.

Comment: @Fang thanks for your feedback, I removed the tag `git` to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I did `brew unlink python && brew reinstall python`, then it works fine.